# how to use python generators

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

today im learning generators iterator and so on in other to save memory,i think rather then have the list dumped in memory its better to have them evaluated when needed so i make a simple test like below a generator like so.

```
def test(*args):
    for i in args:
        yield i
```

when i use it like below it give the desired  effect.

```
for i in test(range(10)):
    print i
```

with output like so

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

but this then range will dump all the number in to the function which defeats the purpose so i tried xrange like below

```
for i in test(xrange(10)):
    print i
```

i get a rather surprising output like this

```
xrange(10)
```

but looking the other way since xrange will only be evaluate when iterated so i try forcing it to do it like so

```
for i in ye(*xrange(10)):
    print i
```

and then i got an output like this

```
o
1
.
.
```

can someone explain what is going on in details please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `*` in a function definition requires the *caller* to provide separate arguments to the function. Consider removing it and using `args` directly.

Comment: ill like to know why i go t each number at a time when i use the star.and what did the star do to the xrange.